# SDWebImage - Image from url didn't replace placeholder image after it's finished download

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uiimageview, lazy-loading

I'm using SDWebImage to download and cache images in an UIImageView asynchronously but I'm facing some problems.

In my project I create a pin marker which has a dialogue box that have UIImageView in it.

The problem that I face is the image from url didn't replace place holder image after it's finished download. The first click on pin marker will always display the place holder image.

The image from url will only display after I click pin marker for the second time.

I want to display image from the url in the first click what should I do?

here is my code

```
    -(UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker{
PlaceData *currentMarker = [self findDataByMarker:marker];

UIView *dialogView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 261, 95)];

// Create background image
UIImageView *dialogBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"MapDialog.png"]];
[dialogView addSubview:dialogBackground];

UIImageView * thumbnail = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

[thumbnail sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentMarker.thumbnail] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];

NSLog(@"URL %@", currentMarker.thumbnail);
NSLog(@"thumbnail %@",thumbnail);



CGRect tmpFrame = thumbnail.frame;
tmpFrame.origin.x = 15;
tmpFrame.origin.y = 14;
tmpFrame.size.width = 55;
tmpFrame.size.height = 55;
thumbnail.frame = tmpFrame;
thumbnail.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
[dialogView addSubview:thumbnail];

return dialogView;
```

PS. Please help me solve this problem and sorry for my english.

Comment: Are you sure imageNamed:@"placeholder.png" Is returning and actual image?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try with this code

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.3 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [thumbnail sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentMarker.thumbnail] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I already change the gif image to png image but it's still doesn't work.

Comment: Use this after add subview:    [thumbnail sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentMarker.thumbnail] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];

Comment: Tried to use the code above but this time there is no image display.

Comment: thats means thumbnail object release

Answer (score 0):

[.retryFailed, .refreshCached] helped solve my issue with this.

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: picnicThumbnail, maxImageSize: 100000, placeholderImage: placeholderImage, options: [.retryFailed, .refreshCached], completion : nil)
```